# Understanding notation of probability of algorithm equal to 1

Tags: probability

I would like to understand what the following notation means:

let $A$ be a polynomial-time algorithm and say $X(a,n)$ is a probability ensemble where $a\in\{0,1\}^*$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

What does the notation $\Pr[A(X(a,n))=1]$ mean?

Comment: there is one closing round bracket missing in $\Pr[A(X(a,n)=1]$

Comment: The algorithm's output is equal to 1. Common notation that exists in all modern books.

Comment: Yes, I understand it outputs 1 but what do we mean by outputting 1 here?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? "It outputs 1." is a relatively straightforward statement. If it's modeled as a Turing machine, it writes "1" to it's output tape. If it's modeled as a circuit it's output wire carries the value "1".

Comment: Let's say $A$ is a PPT distinguisher between two probability ensembles. What do we mean by a distinguisher outputting 1 versus it outputs 0?

Comment: We don't mean anything beyond the obvious: the output of the algorithm is 0 or 1. Whether those values carry any meaning depends on the specific algorithm.